# How to create folder in gist.github repository?

Tags: r, shiny, gist

I let my collogues to run my code by using gist.github and providing them the code to run the gist.

```
shiny::runGist(https://gist.github.com/MyFolder/123ccccc')
```

However, I just added a folder with an Image that I show in my app.The image is in `www` folder.It works fine on localhost but I don't see a way to add the folder to the gist.github.
Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Not tested, but why not move your code to GitHub, then use `runGitHub`?

Comment: gist.github.com is free for a private repository, GitHub is not...